# How to use tf.while_loop() for variable-length inputs in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use `tf.while_loop()` to process variable-length inputs. However, I can only use it for fixed length. The code no longer works after I change `shape=(4)` to `shape=(None)`. `tf.dynamic_rnn` seems to handle variable-length inputs. I am not sure how `tf.dynamic_rnn` achieves this with `tf.while_loop()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
  initial_m = tf.Variable(0.0, name='m')

  inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32', shape=(4))
  #The code no longer works after I change shape=(4) to shape=(None)
  #inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32', shape=(None)) 

  time_steps = tf.shape(inputs)[0]

  initial_outputs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=time_steps)
  initial_t = tf.constant(0, dtype='int32')

  def should_continue(t, *args):
    return t < time_steps

  def iteration(t, m, outputs_):
    cur = tf.gather(inputs, t)
    m  = m * 0.5 + cur * 0.5
    outputs_ = outputs_.write(t, m)
    return t + 1, m, outputs_

  t, m, outputs = tf.while_loop(
    should_continue, iteration,
    [initial_t, initial_m, initial_outputs])

  outputs = outputs.pack()
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run([init])
  print sess.run([outputs], feed_dict={inputs: np.asarray([1,1,1,1])})
```

output (before change):

```
[array([ 0.5   ,  0.75  ,  0.875 ,  0.9375], dtype=float32)]
```

output (after change):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 26, in <module>
    [initial_t, initial_m, initial_outputs])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2636, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2469, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2450, in _BuildLoop
    _EnforceShapeInvariant(m_var, n_var)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 586, in _EnforceShapeInvariant
    % (merge_var.name, m_shape, n_shape))
ValueError: The shape for while/Merge_1:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (), but has shape <unknown> after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works if you remove shapes from all the variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

config = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(
  optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session("", config=config)
#initial_m = tf.Variable(0.0, name='m')

#The code no longer works after I change shape=(4) to shape=(None)
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32', shape=(None)) 
time_steps = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
initial_outputs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=time_steps)
initial_t = tf.placeholder(dtype='int32')
initial_m = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

def should_continue(t, *args):
    return t < time_steps

def iteration(t, m, outputs_):
    cur = tf.gather(inputs, t)
    m  = m * 0.5 + cur * 0.5
    outputs_ = outputs_.write(t, m)
    return t + 1, m, outputs_

t, m, outputs = tf.while_loop(should_continue, iteration,
                              [initial_t, initial_m, initial_outputs])

outputs = outputs.stack()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run([init])
print(sess.run([outputs],
               feed_dict={inputs: np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 1]), initial_t: 0,
                          initial_m: 0.}))
```

Comment: BTW, is it possible to avoid using placeholder? initial_t and initial_m are are alway zeros. Can I avoid injecting zeros for them every time?

Comment: You just need something with unknown shape. It seems it's impossible to make constant with unknown shape. But you could use variable or placeholder

Comment: Is the call to `tf.reset_default_graph()` needed?

Comment: it's when you copy and paste this snippet into existing jupyter notebook, not needed if its stand-alone script

Answer (score 3):

`tf.while_loop` has a keyword parameter called `shape_invariants`. There you can give a list with all tensors' expected shapes, so you can specify which dimensions should remain the same and which are of variable size. For example, you can build your loop like this:

```
t, final_tensor = tf.while_loop(should_continue, iteration,
                                [t0, initial_tensor],
                                [t0.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None,10])])
```

This would allow the `initial_tensor` to change in its first dimension, as long as the second dimension remains of size 10.